# Is Redis single write to master in replication?

Tags: replication, redis

In redis, I guess normally it writes to the Master, and Read from Slave..  And where it (IP address) read from determined by the driver.

So, it is only one place to write?  can I write to slave and then sync with master and other slaves?

Answer (score 3):

You can write to a slave, but there is no way to sync those writes to any other instance without making it the master and the other instances its slaves. Data written to a slave will be overwritten when the same key is written to the master. In general this isn't a very useful feature and you should probably limit your writes to the master only.

Redis Clusters (which are working in redis' development branch, but aren't stable yet) can be configured to allow you to write to any node in a cluster.